# How to Merging two groups in one category in microstrategy

Tags: microstrategy

Currently I have report like:

```
Dept      Sub-Dept      No.Of-Lectures
1           101            2
1           102            3
1           104            1
2           201            3
2           203            4
```

I assume in future `Dept 2` is going to merge into `Dept 1` so that `Sub Dept 201` will report into `Sub 102`.

How can I implement this kind of requirement in MicroStrategy?

Answer (score 0):

There are two way to do it, on the data side or on the MicroStrategy side.

On the data side you have just to modify your fact data to update the `Sub-Dept 201` to `Sub-Dept 102`, modifying the data you can decide to update only after a certain date (not sure if you have a date column in your table) to continue to see the old lectures associated to `Dept 2` and the new ones to `Dept 1`.

On the MicroStrategy side you could create a Custom Group with an element for each `Dept`, except for `Dept 2`, `Dept 1` and `Dept 2` will be part of the same group. Same thing for `Sub-Dept 201`.

Another possible solution in MicroStrategy would be to create logical tables to create an hierarchy like:

```
Dept -> Old Dept -> Sub-Dept -> Old Sub-Dept
```

This will give you a dimension like:

```
Dept  Old Dept  Sub-Dept  Old Sub-Dept
1     1         102       102 
1     2         101       201
```

Then you can hide the attributes `Old Dept` and `Old Sub-Dept` and create a custom drill mapping to jump from `Dept` to `Sub-Dept` ignoring the hidden child.

Not sure how good are you with MicroStrategy and dimensional modelling, maybe my last option could be a little confusing for you.

In my opinion the first option, update the data, is the best, especially if you don't plan to go back to the old department structure.

The second is a good temporary solution, the third one can be a bit of overkill if you can go with the other two.